# why doesn't the email and full Name appear on firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

cant seem to see the email and full name of the registered user on firebase firestore. im having trouble with this for a few hours now and i cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. any tips and help will do thankyou.

```
if(valid){
    //user reg process
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailReg.getText().toString(),passwordReg.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            Toast.makeText(xRegister.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            DocumentReference df = mStore.collection("Users").document(userID);

            Map<String,Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
            userInfo.put("FullName", fullNameReg.getText().toString());
            userInfo.put("Email",emailReg.getText().toString());
            userInfo.put("Student I.D.",studentId.getText().toString());
            //access level of admin an user
            userInfo.put("isUser","1");

            df.set(userInfo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"onsuccess: profile stored!" + userID);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG1,"failure" + e.toString());
                }
            });



            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),xLogin.class));
            finish();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(xRegister.this, "Error Signing Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed? If yes, which one?